# Is there a way to calculate the no of bytes required by the following eastern european character?

Tags: c, character-encoding, sizeof

Is there a way in C language to calculate the no of bytes required by the following eastern european character "`‰`" ? The `sizeof` function won't work because it shows me the standard size of `char`.I know this character requires 3bytes , however i need to get that programmatically?

Comment: C has, since the new C11 standard, four character types: `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`. `char` is a single byte (may be signed or unsigned), `char16_t` is always 16 bits (two bytes), `char32_t` is 32 bits (four bytes), and the size of `wchar_t` depends on the compiler. However, there are no three-byte character types. If you want to use characters using more than 16 bits, then your best bet it to use `char32_t`, or have your own conversion functions to encode in a `int32_t`.

Comment: Perhaps you want its size using the `UTF-8` encoding? Note that, as JoachimPileborg said, it's not the internal encoding used.

Comment: `if(x<(1<<7)) return 1; if(x<(1<<13)) return 2; return 3;` is _I think_, correct for UTF-8 (where `x` is the code point).

Comment: Do you really mean “‰”, U+2030 PER MILLE SIGN? There’s nothing particularly Eastern European about it – it’s globally used as a symbol for one thousandth. I’m asking this because your character might be something completely different and just got somehow turned to the per mille sign.

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
 printf("%d\n",(int)strlen("‰"));
```

Return value:

```
 3
```

Comment: This prints a `size_t` value as `int`, which is not very nice. It also assumes that the source code is in UTF-8 and that the compiler doesn't re-encode strings.

Comment: hmm. to make the cast explicit and still being fast, perhaps `printf("%c\n",(char)strlen()+'0');` would be a nice compromise?

Comment: `%d` is for `int`, not `size_t`, which is what `strlen()` returns. Further, the compiler may not meaningfully support non-ASCII chars in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I decided the output can be cast to int. (even though size_t is typedeffed from an unsigned type). I just know, the result fits into int and that size_t as uint64_t is overkill.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.Thanks AKI

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Aki you can strlen, or you can count bytes in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fn(const char *s)
{
    int n = 0;

    if (*s != '\0') {
        do {
            n++;
            s++;
        } while ((*s & 0xc0) == 0x80);
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", fn("‰"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` is for `int`, not `size_t`, which is what `strlen()` returns. Further, the compiler may not meaningfully support non-ASCII chars in the source code.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, I think your comment goes to answer posted by Aki ;), I don't use strlen in this example

Comment: @David RF, Frunze is right. The compiler decide how encoded your "‰" as literal. You (we) need to tell it we want UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

sizeof can work. I wanted to use:

```
unsigned char a[]="‰"; 
size_t s=sizeof(a)-1;
size_t t=strlen((char*)a);
```

But in VC2012 `s` and `t` are 1. And `a[0]` is 137.
Also, I think what are looking for is exactly [`mblen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mblen)